# How to "load" data from HIVE when the app starts?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I'm trying to add a couple of friends names to a box and then "unbox" every time the app starts in a ListView.builder.** Everything else is in the code working, I tried to copy paste a chunk of the useful code, If something else look wrong, then it's probable because I pasted it wrong. I am pretty new to this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart



void main()  {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget  {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Friends',
   home: myFriends(),

  );}}



  class myFriends extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myFriends createState() => _myFriendsState();
  }

  class _myFriends extends State<myFriends> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  void initState() async{
      await Hive.initFlutter();
      await Hive.openBox("FRIENDS");
    }

     Hive.openBox("FRIENDS");
     var box = Hive.box('FRIENDS');
     List New_List= box.get('Close_Friends');
     print(New_List);


 return MaterialApp(title: "Friends",
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: SafeArea(bottom: false,
          child:Column(Children[
            RaisdButton(onPressed: openAddBox(),)
                    ListView.builder(
                        controller: _scrollController,
                        itemCount: New_List.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(child:
                               Text(New_List[index],)
)})]))));
                                                                 
          
                                                     
                       
openAddBox() async {
    TextEditingController Add_Controller = TextEditingController();

  var ActualW = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(child: AlertDialog(

           content: Container(
              width: ActualW * 0.95,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(height: 45, alignment: Alignment.center,                
                    child: Text(
                      "Add a friend",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: Add_Controller,
                      autofocus: true,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,

                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Peter ... ",
                      ),
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),


                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0), child:
                  Container(alignment: Alignment.center,
                      width: 150,
                      height: 30,
                    
                      child:   InkWell(onTap: (){                         
                        String new_friend = Add_Controller.text;
                           var box = Hive.box('FRIENDS');
                          box.put("Close_Friends", new_friend);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure where you need the data, so I am guessing you need it whenever a certain value changes. Below is an example, so it makes sense on how to update values when a certain box gets updated. And also a recommendation to not use `async` with `initState`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

const darkModeBox = 'darkModeTutorial';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox(darkModeBox);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box(darkModeBox).listenable(),
      builder: (context, box, widget) {
        var darkMode = box.get('darkMode', defaultValue: false);
        return MaterialApp(
          themeMode: darkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Switch(
                value: darkMode,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  box.put('darkMode', !darkMode);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[Source](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/tutorials/dark_mode_switch)

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful!